# Stemmer processor not working

Tags: 8, search

I have configured Search api module in my Drupal 8 search. This is the first time I am configuring search api. I am using database search and not solr. My problem is stemmer processor is not working properly. I am not getting intended result for keywords due to stemmer processor issue. Stemmer processor is not stemming the words while indexing but is stemming while search query is executed. For example the word 'cars' is stored in the database as 'cars' itself while indexing but when a search query for 'cars' is executed it stem the word to 'car' and I am not getting the result. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a bug. I run into the same problem today, so I created an issue on the search api queue [Stemmer is not working properly on indexing or on search](https://www.drupal.org/node/2922024). Please check that issue and elaborate if necessary.